# OR gate with inverted inputs

Tags: binary, logic, addition

This is a general question..

How does the math behind the first set of input work (0,0), since the inputs get inverted (0,0) becomes (1,1) which if we then add becomes a 2 ('0b10') how is the output '1'.

[image: Inverted Input OR Gate]

Comment: Or gates are electronics, what does this have to do with Python?

Comment: `OR` is not addition.

Comment: Oh I see, I was looking at the Boolean expression for it, and it had this addition which I realized is read as 'OR'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR is not the same as integer addition. The truth table for an OR gate is

```
A   B     A OR B
0   0       0
0   1       1
1   0       1
1   1       1
```

The output is 1 if and only if A is 1 *or* B is 1 (hence the name).

The truth table shown is not for a NOR gate, but rather a NAND gate. One of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) states that

```
NOT A OR NOT B == NOT (A AND B)
```

and you can see this is the case:

```
A   B     A OR B  A AND B   NOT (A AND B)
0   0       0        0           1
0   1       1        0           1
1   0       1        0           1
1   1       1        1           0
```

---

If I see "Negative-OR", I assume they mean NOR. Whoever created that image may have intended it to be read "input-negative OR", which matches the symbol and the truth table, but isn't a term I've ever heard before.

Comment: Thanks for adding the mention of De Morgan's Laws.

Comment: Is there a mathematical method to calculate an AND gate's output?

Comment: AND and OR are multiplication and addition, respectively, modulo 2. (That is, `A AND B  == (A*B) % 2` and `A OR B == (A + B) % 2`.)

Comment: When using the AND Gates on two bits. For example: 1 and 0 = you can just multiply 1 * 0 = 0, but what can you change to do the same for two integers 3 and 6?